# Block concurrent access ThreadPool

Tags: c#, multithreading

So I'm running a query and processing the rows that return concurrently using a function called **StartJob** that will work on my **job**:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(StartJob, job);
```

Works great and is very fast. But now I'm told that when the query returns, some rows may have the same value for job.UserID and that we can't be running the StartJob function concurrently for identical values of job.UserID. The question is: how can I have StartJob block execution until any other instances of StartJob with the same UserID have completed?

I'm sure there's a some way to obtain a per-UserID lock, but I don't know how to do it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: There will be no concurrency clash if you run StartJob with same job.UserID until it targets to some shared resource like a file or row in database. Could you show what are you doing in StartJob?

Comment: What version of .NET? 3.5 or 4.0?

Comment: @invisible exactly right, I'm running more queries in StartJob which lock rows owned by UserID and so we're seeing timesout because these long-running queries are locking those rows. So I'd like to start StartJob with some lock specific to UserID and just block there until it's free.

Comment: if you have to do same operation over the same row with the same id won't it be the same action? i mean why do you need to do that same multiple times? maybe you just need to drop duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HashSet<int> hs = new HashSet<int>(); // In common with all the threads

int id = 1; // Your id

// This is the body of your Thread. You pass it the id as you want. 
// A closure on it, or as a parameter of the thread.

// This will begin with short spins, every time trying to add the id to the hashset.
// SpinUntil stops when the lambda function returns true.
SpinWait.SpinUntil(() =>
{
    lock (cd)
    {
        return hs.Add(id);
    }
});

// OR, if you know the operation is slow, or < .NET 4.0

// This is clearer. The thread yields until it can add the id to the hashset.
while (true)
{
    lock (hs)
    {
        if (hs.Add(id))
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    Thread.Yield();
}

// End of the variant

// Remember the try/finally! It's important in case of exceptions!!!
try
{
    // Put here your code
    // Put here your code
    // Put here your code
}
finally
{
    lock (hs)
    {
        hs.Remove(id);
    }
}
```

Two versions, one that is good for short `StartJob` and works only on .NET 4.0, one that works with .NET >= 3.5.

Clearly `hs` is in common between all the threads, and `id` is the `job.UserID`.

I'll add that under .NET 4.0 you could use `SpinLock` instead of `lock`. It is a little faster, but its syntax is a little tricky.

Answer (score 1):

use task parallel library

```
var tasks = new Dictionary<int, Task>();

QueueJob(Job job)
{
    lock(tasks)
      if (tasks.ContainsKey(job.UserID))
      {
         var newTask = tasks[job.UserID].ContinueWith(_=>StartJob(job));
         tasks[job.UserID] = newTask;
      }
      else
            tasks[job.UserID] = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>StartJob(job));                  
}
```

Comment: Not task.ContinueWith, lastTask.ContinueWith

Comment: @xanatos that's not possible. Try it.

Comment: Right... And `var newTask = lastTask.ContinueWith(_ => StartJob(job));`?